# Accessing values passed into a prototype function

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to access the string of the object and that passed into the function but don't know how to. **split** is not allowed here:

```
var Result = { "win": 1, "loss": 2, "tie": 3 }

function PokerHand(hand) {
}
PokerHand.prototype.compareWith = function(hand){
    // Start your coding here...
    var myHand = this.hand.split(' ');
    var opHand = hand.split(' ');
    if (myHand[0] > opHand[0])
      return Result.win;
    if (this.hand != hand)
      return Result.win;
    return Result.tie;
}
var player = "4S 5H 6H TS AC";
var opponent =  "3S 5H 6H TS AC";
var p = new PokerHand(player);
var o = new PokerHand(opponent);
p.compareWith(o)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It works. The argument in the compareWith() function should be a PokerHand, not a hand. So, I just did player.hand in places where hand was used.

One more thing, the PokerHand constructor needs to have a hand property.

```js
var Result = { "win": 1, "loss": 2, "tie": 3 }

function PokerHand(hand) {
  this.hand = hand;
}
PokerHand.prototype.compareWith = function(pokerHand){
    // Start your coding here...
    var myHand = this.hand.split(' ');
    var opHand = pokerHand.hand.split(' ');
    if (myHand[0] > opHand[0])
      return Result.win;
    if (this.hand != pokerHand.hand)
      return Result.win;
    return Result.tie;
}
var player = "4S 5H 6H TS AC";
var opponent =  "3S 5H 6H TS AC";
var p = new PokerHand(player);
var o = new PokerHand(opponent);
console.log(p.compareWith(o))
```

Comment: I still get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

Comment: Why do you need this line? `this.hand = hand;`

Comment: Its because an Object.constructor must have a Object.property where it can store the object data. So when you call the PokerHand constructor and pass a hand, it must be set on the PokerHand Object instance. 'this' refers to the Object in the constructor. Thus. this.hand = hand basically stores the hand on particular PokerHand Object instance.

Comment: The logic should probably be `if (this.hand != pokerHand.hand) return Result.loss;` but might be clearer as `if (this.hand < pokerHand.hand) ...`.

Comment: Or `return Result[this.hand > pokerHand.hand? 'win' : this.hand < pokerHand.hand? 'loss' : 'tie']`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Thanks. I haven't finished the algorithm. I was stuck with the above issue.